# Java azure-function deployment bitbucket pipeline, gives NoSuchMethodException. How to resolve dependencies of another dependent project?

Tags: java, azure-functions, nosuchmethoderror

I have two java projects. A java azure function, with another child maven project. This another project have other dependencies like, jackson-databind, apache etc. Using bitbucket pipeline, i am able to successfully deploy it on azure. But while running, it is not able to read dependencies of child dependent project. Though all my parent/child jars are fat jars, the lib folder under target, doesnt include dependencies of child dependent project. It has dependency of child project though. On local, the lib folder contains all dependencies, please suggest what should be on pipeline.

Tried with below configuration

[bitbucket-pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgiaH.png)

getting NoSuchMethodError, though the .class file is present.